# YouTube Content ID API, intermittent 500 errors

Tags: youtube-api

I am getting intermittent 500 errors when hitting the YouTube ContentID/partner API. At times, this is the response:

```
{"errors":[{"domain":"youtubePartner","reason":"internalError","message":"An internal error has occurred."}],"code":500,"message":"An internal error has occurred."}
```

At other times, this is the response

```
{"code":500,"message":null}
```

And at other times, the request succeeds.

This is happening most often when [inserting a claim](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/claims/insert), next most often when [setting ownership](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/ownership/update) and, less often but still happening, when [creating an asset](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/assets/insert) and when [setting advertising options](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/videoAdvertisingOptions/update).

Is there any alternative to adding retry logic?

Answer (score 0):

There are most likely transient errors, you can just implement an exponential backoff retry policy and that would do best for now.
On the other hand, issue should've been fixed by now.